# Can't connect to an external service from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, service

I have an assembly DLL that lets me connect to an ActiveMQ broker. Using the DLL from NUnit works fine and using it from a Console app works fine too. The problem is using it from a Windows Service. The connection to the broker always fails, as if there's no external connectivity available to the service. Even bypassing the SCM and running the code in Visual Studio fails. Is there anything special a Windows Service project needs to do to get external connections?

The failing code in the DLL is this:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(connectURI);
connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection(); // fails here
```

the connectURI is fine as it works in the Console app and the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main differnce is a console app and NUnit is running as the logged on user.  A windows service runs as whatever you configure it to run as.

Try configuring the service to run as your account and see if it works.  Make sure it's not running as network service or local service.

The account it's running as may need a user profile (has logged on before) especially if using a proxy server.

Try running [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [netmon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812953) to see what's going on in the attempted connection.  Also, try adding some logging and tracing around the connection attempt - the exception stack should have more details.

EDIT from comments:  Also try adding .net web client connect code which will give a better insight into whatever connectivity issue there is.  Obviously NMS is masking and swallowing the root issue.

EDIT: for others looking for the solution (without reading all the comments), adding the .web client code exposed the root issue which was a config file issue.

Comment: I've tried every user on offer, LocalSystem, LocalService, NetworkService, even Administrator, none of them work. Also it doesn't even work debugging in Visual Studio. Connection is not authenticating. I use log4net to catch the exception but it just says: Apache.NMS.NMSConnectionException was caught and "Error in application". I presume debugging in Visual Studio will also cause it to run as the logged in user but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Debugging in Visual Studio will not make it run as the logged on user - it will run as what it's configured to run as in SCM - the debugger runs as you and attaches to that process.

Comment: Try configuring to run as your account Inot NS, LS or administrator).  Make sure the account you choose is an account you just ran it as interactively in the console app.  That will rule out user being the issue.

Comment: You can also add some code using a straight .net web client class to see if that can make a succesfull request.  Or, get the code for NMS and debug into it.

Comment: I'm bypassing the SCM in Visual Studio (have moved the connection code to temp method and not running service start) and running the connection code directly in the debugger, rather than connecting to a running service. Still won't connect. Copy/pasting the code into a Console app works.

Comment: you hit on it! I took up your suggestiong of using a standard WebClient and that didn't work but it pointed out the error: Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration> element. That was the problem, AppConfig wasn't conforming to the schema! Would never have worked that out so thanks for the suggestion that led to the fix